# Alignment Measurements after hitting a curb

Tags: alignment, accident, measurement

I hit a curb with my front right tire. I hit with an angle and with 25-30 Miles per hour speed. I took my vehicle to an auto pair, and surprisingly they told me that nothing is bent or damaged. They only aligned the vehicle and gave me the below chart. Would you please advise me if the alignment measurements is good?

```
Front Measurements

                         Before          |           After
                     Left  |    Right    |     Left    |    Right
Camber              -0.80  |    -1.20    |    -0.80    |    -1.20 
Caster               2.7   |     1.4     |     2.7     |     1.40 
Toe                 -0.01  |    0.61     |     0.10    |    -0.06
SAI                 12.1   |    11.70    |     12.1*   |    11.70*
Included Angle      11.3   |    10.50    |     11.3    |    10.50*
-------------------------------------------------------------------
                                         |           
Cross Camber              0.40           |           0.40
Cross Caster              1.3            |           1.3*
Cross SAI                 0.3            |           0.4
Total Toe                 0.60           |           0.04

___________________________________________________________________
Rear Measurements

                        Before           |           After
                     Left  |    Right    |     Left    |    Right
Camber               0.00  |    -2.2     |     0.0     |    -2.20*
Toe                  0.44  |     0.16    |     0.22    |     0.16
-------------------------------------------------------------------
                                         |           
Cross Camber              2.20           |           2.2*
Total Toe                 0.59           |           0.38
Thrust Angle              0.14           |           0.03
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. To me it appears the toe in the front measurements is a little wacky, with the total toe being not very much. This doesn't show what the spec if for your car, so it could be within reason. I guess I'd ask you if the car wonders a lot when on a straight/flat road? They didn't change a whole lot, that's for sure.

Comment: What is the year make and model of your car? It should drive straight but all they did was adjust your front toe. You're mismatched Left to Right and looks like your right caster is considerably off so you might have a bent strut.